# Return a reference of a std::vector

Tags: c++, reference

I'm having problems with some code. I have a class which contains a vector of `unique_ptr` of an object but when I try to return it I have an error.

> Error :  error: unvalid initialization pour of a reference of type « const `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<AEntity> >&` » from an expression of type « `const std::vector<std::unique_ptr<SFEntity> >` »

Here is the code :

```
class a {
    public:
const std::vector<std::unique_ptr<AEntity>> &getEntity() const;
    private:
const std::vector<std::unique_ptr<SFEntity>> m_entity;
};

const std::vector<std::unique_ptr<AEntity>> &a::getEntity() const
{
    return m_entity;
}
```

SFEntity inherit from AEntity.

Comment: `vector<X>` and `vector<Y>` are two different types, no matter how `X` and `Y` are related.

Comment: i guess you are missing const reference '&' for m_entity

Comment: @MarKS the return type is a const reference, `m_entity` is just a plain value

Comment: @user463035818 oh yes! sorry i missed it.

Answer (score 1):

A vector of pointer of derived class won't automated convert to a vector of pointer of base class.
The container are different type.